# How to revert changes with procedural memory?

Tags: memory, logic, procedural

Is it possible to store all changes of a set by using some means of logical paths - of the changes as they occur - such that one may revert the changes by essentially "stepping back"? I assume that something would need to map the changes as they occur, and the process of reverting them would thus ultimately be linear.

Apologies for any incoherence and this isn't applicable to any particular language. Rather, it's a problem of memory – i.e. can a set * (e.g. which may be some store of user input)* of a finite size that's changed continuously * (e.g. at any given time for any amount of time - there's no limit with regards to how much it can be changed)* be mapped procedurally such that new - future - changes are assumed to be the consequence of prior change * (in a second, mirror store that can be used to revert the state of the set all the way to its initial state)*.

Comment: Certainly it's possible. Almost anything is possible. Can you clarify your question so that it's more specific so it can be answerable? As it is, I've already answered it with my first two sentences. You haven't even mentioned what language you're using. If you don't make it more specific, this question will most likely be closed.

Comment: I've updated with an attempt to clarify the question.

Comment: It's still "is it possible?", which is very vague. (Actually, it changed to "can it be done?", which isn't any better.) Questions should be clear, concise, and specific, so that a single answer can be chosen as correct. This is still answerable by "yes, it can be done" or "no, it can't be done" with no other explanation given. (Actually, "maybe, depending on your specific needs" could be a valid answer as well.)

Comment: Apologies, but I'm unsure of how else I should express the question.  Essentially, I want to know if a memory store (referred to as a set in the OP) of a finite size can have all of its changes (states) stored procedurally.

Comment: Apologies, but I'd still like to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at some functional data structures.  Functional languages, like Erlang, make it easy to roll back to the earlier state, since changes are always made on new data structures instead of mutating existing ones.  While this feature can be used at repeatedly internally, Erlang programming typically uses this abundantly at the top level of a "process" so that on any kind of failure, it aborts both processing as well as all the changes in their entirety simply by throwing an exception (in a non-functional language, using mutable data structures, you'd be able to throw an exception to abort, but restoring originals would be your program's job not the runtime's job).  This is one reason that Erlang has a solid reputation.

Some of this functional style of programming is usefully applied to non-functional languages, in particular, use of immutable data structures, such as immutable sets, lists, or trees.

Regarding immutable sets, for example, one might design a functionally-oriented data structure where modifications always generate a new set given some changes and an existing set (a change set consisting of additions and removals).  You'd leave the old set hanging around for reference (by whomever); languages with automatic garbage collection reclaim the old ones when they're no longer being used (referenced).

You can put a id or tag into your set data structure, this way you can do some introspection to see what data structure id someone has a hold of.  You also can capture the id of the base off of which each new version was generated; this gives you some history or lineage.

If desired, you can also capture a reference to the entire old data structure in the new one, or, one can maintain a global list of all of the sets as they are being generated.  If you do, however, you'll have to take over more responsibility for storage management, as an automatic collector will probably not find any unused (unreferenced) garbage to collect without additional some help.

Database designs do some of this in their transaction controllers.  For the purposes of your question, you can think of a database as a glorified set.  You might look into MVCC (Multi-version Concurrency Control) as one example that is reasonably well written up in literature.  This technique keeps old snapshot versions of data structures around (temporarily), meaning that mutations always appear to be in new versions of the data.  An old snapshot is maintained until no active transaction references it; then is discarded.  When two concurrently running transactions both modify the database, they each get a new version based off the same current and latest data set.  (The transaction controller knows exactly which version each transaction is based off of, though the transaction's client doesn't see the version information.)  Assuming both concurrent transactions choose to commit their changes, the versioning control in the transaction controller recognizes that the second committer is trying to commit a change set that is not a logical successor to the first (since both changes sets as we postulated above were based on the same earlier version).  If possible, the transaction controller will merge the changes as if the 2nd committer was really working off the other, newer version committed by the first committer.  (There are varying definitions of when this is possible, MVCC says it is when there are no write conflicts, which is a less-than-perfect answer but fast and scalable.)  But if not possible, it will abort the 2nd committers transaction and inform the 2nd committer thereof (they then have the opportunity, should they like, to retry their transaction starting from the newer base).  Under the covers, various snapshot versions in flight by concurrent transactions will probably share the bulk of the data (with some transaction-specific change sets that are consulted first) in order to make the snapshots cheap. There is usually no API provided to access older versions, so in this domain, the transaction controller knows that as transactions retire, the original snapshot versions they were using can also be (reference counted and) retired.

Another area this is done is using Append-Only-Files.  Logging is a way of recording changes; some databases are based 100% on log-oriented designs.

BerkeleyDB has a nice log structure.  Though used mostly for recovery, it does contain all the history so you can recreate the database from the log (up to the point you purge the log in which case you should also archive the database).  Again someone has to decide when they can start a new log file, and when they can purge old log files, which you'd do to conserve space.

These database techniques can be applied in memory as well.  (Nothing is free, though, of course ;)

Anyway, yes, there are fields where this is done.

1. Immutable data structures help preserve history, by simply keeping old copies; changes always go to new copies.  (And efficiency techniques can make this not as bad as it sounds.)
2. Id's can help understand lineage without necessarily holding onto all the old copies.
3. If you do want to hold onto all old the copies, you have to look at your domain design to understand when/how/if old data structures possibly can get accessed with an eye toward how to eventually reclaim them.  You'll mostly likely have to help get involved in defining how they get released, if ever.  Or how they get archived for posterity though at the cost of slower access later.

Comment: I thoroughly appreciate your response, however it doesn't seem to address the problem I proposed.  I mean, it doesn't describe a set which may retain all changes procedurally such that its actual size never changes -- i.e. no additional storage space that is greater than the size of the set itself is used to revert such changes, so the set could theoretically store as much as desired if using such a procedural technique to revert changes.  It seems that something to map those changes and perhaps to map the map of them also.  Thus, the map itself may be defined procedurally by its own means.

Comment: The problem however - if such structure is possible - is how? How can this be done? Also note that this automatically assumes that the current destination of the set can be accomplished linearly via its procedural mapping method.